# Stripe Webhook Error: 400 Bad Request in Express.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, stripe-payments

Title: Stripe Webhook Error: 400 Bad Request in Express.js

I am working on an Express.js app and using Stripe to handle payments. I have implemented a webhook to receive data from Stripe after a successful checkout. However, I am encountering a 400 Bad Request error when testing the webhook. Here is my code:

```js
// Require necessary modules
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
const { verifyToken } = require("./verifyToken");
const Order = require("../model/Order");
const router = express.Router();
const stripe = require("stripe")(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);

// Handle POST request for creating a checkout session
router.post("/checkout", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const cartItems = req.body.cartItem;

        // Create a customer with the given details
        const customer = await stripe.customers.create({
            email: cartItems[0].email,
            name: cartItems[0].username,
        });

        const lineItems = cartItems.map((item) => {
            return {
                price_data: {
                    currency: "usd",
                    product_data: {
                        name: item.title,
                        images: [item.image],
                    },
                    unit_amount: item.price * 100, // Convert the price from USD to cents
                },
                quantity: item.quantity,
            };
        });

        const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
            shipping_address_collection: {
                allowed_countries: ["TH", "KH", "VN", "LA"],
            },
            line_items: lineItems,
            payment_method_types: ["card"],
            mode: "payment",
            success_url: "http://localhost:5173/checkout",
            cancel_url: "http://localhost:5173/cart",
            customer: customer.id,
            phone_number_collection: {
                enabled: true,
            },
        });

        res.json({ url: session.url });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error creating checkout session:", error);
        res.status(500).json({ error: "An error occurred during checkout." });
    }
});

// Stripe Webhook
const endpointSecret =
    "whsec_5a72132b34843b92525fbe38b95550eb169ba00c2c7ac12b42743b3ceff4a647";

router.post(
    "/webhook",
    express.raw({ type: "application/json" }),
    (request, response) => {
        const sig = request.headers["stripe-signature"];
        let event;

        try {
            event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(
                request.body,
                sig,
                endpointSecret
            );
        } catch (err) {
            response.status(400).send(`Webhook Error: ${err.message}`);
            return;
        }

        // Handle the event
        switch (event.type) {
            case "payment_intent.succeeded":
                const paymentIntentSucceeded = event.data.object;
                // Call a function to handle the event payment_intent.succeeded
                break;
            // Handle other event types
            default:
                console.log(`Unhandled event type ${event.type}`);
        }

        // Return a 200 response to acknowledge receipt of the event
        response.send().end();
    }
);

module.exports = router;

// index.js
app.use("/api/stripe", stripeRouter);
```

Comment: As in your `response.status(400)` line is being triggered? Or is the 400 coming from somewhere else? If so, please provide more detail on exactly where you are getting the 400

Comment: It come from triggered, when I to use try cmd "stripe trigger payment_intent.succeeded" , I was 400

Comment: @Pompey 
payment_intent.succeeded [evt_3N8GuPInQBT878NO0hKa5h4K]                               [400] POST http://localhost:3000/api/stripe/webhook[evt_3N8GuPInQBT878NO0hKa5h4K]

Comment: That 400 is coming from your server. Have you tried stepping through your code to see where and why it is throwing a 400?